# Cassandra Cluster with 2 Nodes got Read TimeOut/NoHostAvailable Exception

Tags: azure, cassandra, timeout, database, nosql

I am implementing a recommendation engine in .Net C#, I am using Cassandra to store the data. I am still new in using C*, just started using it 2 months ago. At the moment I have only 2 nodes in my cluster (single DC), deployed in Azure DS2 VM (each has 7Gb RAM, 2 Cores). I set `RF=2, CL=1` for both read and write. I set the timeouts in yaml config file as below

```
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 120000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 120000
request_timeout_in_ms: 120000
```

I set lower read query timeout in client side (30 secs each).
The data stored in cassandra is user history, item counter, and recommended items data. I created an API (stands in equinix DC) for my recommendation engine, its work is very simple, only reading all recommended_items Id from recommended_items table in C* everytime a user opens the website page. It means that the query is very simple for each user :

```cql
select * from recommended_items where username = <username>
```

When I did load testing for up to 500 users/threads, it was fine and very fast. But when the online site calls API to read from C* table, I got read timeouts very often. There were usually only less than 20 users at the same time though. 
I monitor the cassandra nodes activity using DataDog and I found that only node #2 that keeps getting timeouts (the seed node is node #1, though what I understand is seed doesn't really matter except during bootstrapping step). However, everytime the timeout happens, I tried to query using cqlsh in both nodes, and node #1 is the one that return

> OperationTimeOut Exception.

I have been trying to find the main root of this issue. Does that have anything to do with coordinator node being down ([I read this article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure)) ? Or is that because I have only 2 nodes?

When the timeout happens (the webpage shows nothing), then I tried to refresh the page that calls the API, it will be loading for long time before showing nothing again (because of the timeout). But surprisingly, I will get the log that all those requests were actually successful after few minutes even though the web page has been closed. It's like the read request was still running even though the page has been closed.

The exception are like these (they didn't happen together) :

```
None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: 13.73.193.140:9042,13.75.154.140:9042)
```

OR

```
Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LocalOne (0 replica(s) responded over 1 required)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about my problem? thank you.

output of cfstats .recommended_items

**NODE #1**

```
 Read Count: 683
    Read Latency: 2.970781844802343 ms.
    Write Count: 0
    Write Latency: NaN ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: recommendedvideos
            Space used (live): 96034775
            Space used (total): 96034775
            Space used by snapshots (total): 40345163
            Off heap memory used (total): 192269
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.4405242717559795
            Number of keys (estimate): 101493
            Memtable cell count: 0
            Memtable data size: 0
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 376
            Local read latency: 1.647 ms
            Local write count: 0
            Local write latency: NaN ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 126928
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 126896
            Index summary off heap memory used: 40085
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 25288
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 43
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 454826
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 2201
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 160.28657799274487
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2759
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Dropped Mutations: 0
```

**NODE #2**

```
Read Count: 733
    Read Latency: 3.0032783083219647 ms.
    Write Count: 0
    Write Latency: NaN ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: recommendedvideos
            Space used (live): 99145806
            Space used (total): 99145806
            Space used by snapshots (total): 15101127
            Off heap memory used (total): 196008
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.44063804831658704
            Number of keys (estimate): 103863
            Memtable cell count: 0
            Memtable data size: 0
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 453
            Local read latency: 1.344 ms
            Local write count: 0
            Local write latency: NaN ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 129056
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 129040
            Index summary off heap memory used: 40856
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 26112
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 43
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 454826
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 2264
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 170.7715877437326
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2759
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Comment: Hello, Christa. It definitely sounds like the nodes are getting overloaded. Do you see a lot of dropped reads/mutations in the logs? You'd probably also see lots of long-ish GC taking place. Are you able to attach the `system.log` from the nodes? Also attach the `nodetool cfstats <keyspace>. recommended_items` output from both nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, @flightc, thank you for your response. I checked my 'system.log' and the GCInspector processes happen every hour and they took 1-2 seconds on average, sometimes less than 1 sec, I also monitor the dropped task using 'watch -n 1 nodetool netstats' and indeed, at node #1 it shows 10-15 dropped tasks, while node #2 always shows 0 dropped task. So do you have any suggestion about this? I attached the output of my cfstats above. :)

Comment: hello, the command with `watch` increase load of node! 
can I know why you change the timeout defaults?